# JPA Named query with INNER JOIN condition is failing

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, named-query

I'm trying to create a Named query with the inner join condition in the Entity class. 
However the application is failing to start with an exception.

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "fooentry")
@NamedQuery(name="query1", query="SELECT  foo.id, foo.name, foo.type, foo.action, foo.createdDateTime FROM FooEntity foo " +
        "INNER JOIN (SELECT  name, type, MAX(createdDateTime) AS recenttime FROM FooEntity GROUP BY  name, type) recententry " +
        "ON (foo.name = recententry.name AND foo.type = recententry.type) AND createdDateTime = recenttime AND isExported = false",
        lockMode=PESSIMISTIC_WRITE)
public class FooEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    @NotNull
    private String msisdn;

    @Column(name = "type")
    @NotNull
    private String iccid;

    @Column(name = "action")
    @NotNull
    private Long inventoryActionId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "is_exported")
    private Boolean isExported;

    @Column(name = "created_date_time")
    @NotNull
    private LocalDateTime createdDateTime;

    //setter and getter

}
```

Exception:
Application is failing to start with the following exception.

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: 
query1 failed because of: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: ( near line 1, column 161
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try query like below. It should return expected result

```
SELECT foo.id, foo.name, foo.type, foo.action, foo.createdDateTime 
FROM FooEntity foo 
WHERE  
    foo.isExported = false AND
    EXISTS(
        SELECT recententry.name, recententry.type, MAX(recententry.createdDateTime) AS recenttime 
        FROM FooEntity recententry 
        WHERE recententry.name = foo.name AND recententry.type = foo.type 
        GROUP BY recententry.name, recententry.type 
        HAVING recententry.recenttime = foo.createdDateTime
    )
```